# Print all file with extension inside root folder with their folder path in Mac using Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, command, applescript

I want to list all files along with their paths(contains root folder-> sub folder(if any) till file exists) in Mac using Terminal.

```
         |FolderA -> FolderAA -> FolderAAA -> test.swift
Folder ->|FolderB -> FolderB -> FolderBB -> samp.swift
         |FolderC -> new.swift

Result:
 /Folder/FolderA/FolderAA/FolderAAA/test.swift
 /Folder/FolderB/FolderB/FolderBB/samp.swift
 /Folder/FolderC/new.swift
```

Answer (score 0):

This following shell script searches for files ending with ".swift" starting from the root directory.

`find / -name "*.swift" -mindepth 1 2>/dev/null`

This following shell script searches for files ending with ".swift" starting from the home directory.

`find ~ -name "*.swift" -mindepth 1`

Comment: Not sure whether I'm interpreting the question properly but won't this find results that are outside of the 'Folder' tree? Separately, wouldn't it also run more quickly if you isolated on 'Folder'? e.g. `find "/Folder" -name "*.swift"`.